# A question related to the card game "Set"

Tags: combinatorics

The card game [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(card_game)) lead to the following question. Lets call a subset $A$ of $(\mathbb{Z}/3)^n$ dependent, if there is $\{x,y,z\}\subset A$ with $x+y+z=0$. (So unlike the case of linear dependence we are not allowing any coefficients here).

Let $f(n)$ denote the maximal size of a independent subset of $(\mathbb{Z}/3)^n$.
Is there an explicit expression / a recursion for $f(n)$? Can anything be said about its asymptotic behaviour (like $f\in O(c^n)$ for some minimal $c$)?

As $\{0;1\}^n$ is independent, we know that $f(n)\ge 2^n$. And so $c\ge 2$.
The card game set deals with the case $n=4$ and $f(4)=20$ if I remember correctly.

Comment: You may be interested in some of the discussion around Polymath1, which I believe tackles similar questions.

Comment: $f(4)=20$ is correct--that is, 20 is the minimum number of SET cards needed to guarantee a "set" in the context of the game.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Both answers I got are contradicting each other, as the given recursion does not satisfy the claimed lower bound c>2. Furthermore In this presentation is sounded like its unknown,whether this recursion holds (it is in the chapter further work and it is followed by a ?-sign). Anyhow I am a bit confused right now.

Comment: You claimed c≥2, which the formulas I gave do satisfy (as it is O(2^n), so c=2).  On a second look, you're right that the presentation to which I linked does not quite make it clear whether or not these formulas (which are not recursive) are correct, but that was how I read it and the formulas do seem to work for n=2, 3, 4, 5, and 6.

Comment: "We have a lower bound of order c^n for some c > 2" I think this statement in harrisons answer contradicts the suggested formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematicians call these "independent sets" *capsets*, and they're fairly widely studied. But surprisingly, we don't know much about their asymptotic behavior! We have a lower bound of order c^n for some c > 2; and we have an upper bound of order about 3^n/n (although this is not in the least trivial to prove!) Most mathematicians seem to suspect that the upper bound can't be improved to c^n for c strictly less than 3, but no one's sure how to prove this.

For more information (perhaps a little out-of-date, but I don't think much has changed) see Terry Tao's [discussion](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/02/23/open-question-best-bounds-for-cap-sets/).

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this presentation](http://www2.truman.edu/~erickson/presentation7.ppt) (PPT; [Google-based HTML conversion](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3a-7EZGJG-DWEJ%3awww2.truman.edu/~erickson/presentation7.ppt+proof+of+minimum+number+of+%22set+cards%22+to+guarantee+a+set&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)), I think a formula for your $f(n)$ is:
$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
\frac{2^{n+2}-4}{3} & \text{ if }n\text{ is even}
\\
\frac{2^{n+2}-5}{3} & \text{ if }n>1\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

Recently, Jordan Ellenberg and Dion Gijswijt have proved using the ideas of Croot-Lev-Pach, that $f(n) \in O(2.756^n)$.

This is the best possible bound we have so far. See the preprints, https://quomodocumque.files.wordpress.com/2016/05/cap-set.pdf and http://homepage.tudelft.nl/64a8q/progressions.pdf ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160611180115/http://homepage.tudelft.nl/64a8q/progressions.pdf)). Also see the blog post ``[Mind Boggling: Following the work of Croot, Lev, and Pach, Jordan Ellenberg settled the cap set problem!](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2016/05/15/mind-boggling-following-the-work-of-croot-lev-and-pach-jordan-ellenberg-settled-the-cap-set-problem/)'' by Gil Kalai.

The upper bound they have obtained can also be stated as "*a cap set has size bounded above by the number of monomials $x_1^{e_1}x_2^{e_2}\cdots x_n^{e_n}$ of total degree at most $2n/3$ that satisfy $0 \leq e_i \leq 2$ for all $i$.}*".

The beautiful proof can be summarised as follows (take $q = 3$ for capsets).

Let $q$ be an odd prime power and let $\mathcal{P}_d(n, q)$ denote the set of all polynomials $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_q[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ that satisfy $\deg f \leq d$ and $\deg_{x_i} f \leq q - 1$ for all $i$, aka, the set of reduced polynomials of degree at most $d$. The set of all reduced polynomials with no restriction on the total degree is simply denoted by $\mathcal{P}(n, q)$. There is a vector space isomorphism between $\mathcal{P}(n, q)$ and the space of all $\mathbb{F}_q$-valued functions on $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ given by evaluating the polynomial.

For a $3$-term arithmetic progression free subset $A$ of $\mathbb{F}_q^n$, the sets $A + A = \{a + a' : a, a' \in A, a \neq a'\}$ and $2A = \{a + a : a \in A\}$ are disjoint.
Let $U$ be the subspace of $\mathcal{P}(n, q)$ consisting of all the polynomials that vanish on the complement of $2A$.
Then $\dim U = |2A| = |A|$ (since $q$ is odd) and thus we try to find upper bounds on $\dim U$.
For any integer $d \in \{0, 1, \dots, n(q - 1)\}$ let $U_d$ be the intersection of $\mathcal{P}_d(n, q)$ with $U$.
Then since $\langle U, \mathcal{P}_d(n, q) \rangle \leq \mathcal{P}(n, q)$ we have $\dim U \leq \dim \mathcal{P}(n, q) - \dim \mathcal{P}_d(n, q) + \dim U_d$.

Now the crux of the proof is Proposition 1 in Jordan's preprint, which says that every (reduced) polynomial of degree at most $d$ which vanishes on $A + A$ has at most $2 \dim P_{d/2}(n, q)$ non-zeros in $2A$.
Since $A + A$ is a subset of the complement of $2A$, we see that every element of $U_d$, when seen as an element of $\mathbb{F}_q^{\mathbb{F}_q^n}$ via the evaluation isomorphism, has at most $2 \dim \mathcal{P}_{d/2} (n, q)$ non-zero coordinates, and thus $\dim U_d \leq 2 \dim \mathcal{P}_{d/2}(n, q)$.

Therefore, we get $|A| = \dim U \leq q^n - \dim \mathcal{P}_d(n, q) + 2 \dim \mathcal{P}_{d/2}(n, q) = \dim \mathcal{P}_{n(q - 1) - d} (n, q) + 2\dim P_{d/2}(n, q)$.
Finally observe that $n(q - 1) - d = d/2$ when $d = 2(q - 1)n/3$ which gives us the bound $$|A| \leq 3 \dim \mathcal{P}_{(q - 1)n/3}(n, q)$$ (whenever $(q - 1)n/3$ is an integer).
The reason why this is a good bound is that $\dim \mathcal{P}_{d}(n, q)$ is bounded above by $q^{\lambda n}$ for some $\lambda < 1$ when $d < (q - 1)n/2$ (see the preprints).