# Mathematics related to the card game SET

Tags: combinatorics

Last month, I was introduced to the card game SET. The game raises several interesting questions eg what's the probability that n randomly drawn cards contain k sets, is it possible to end with 12 (or 15) cards which contain no sets... I would like to present the solution to a question like this to undergrads, and through it introduce them to an area of mathematics. For example, as [mentioned previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6190/a-question-related-to-the-card-game-set), there is the issue of maximal caps, which [Davis and MacLagan's paper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28game%29#Variations) relates to projective space and error-correcting codes. Can you give me any similar ideas? Perhaps relating to a variation of SET [listed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28game%29#Variations)?

Comment: Nice game, I was introduced to it by a Hungarian friend a few years ago.

Comment: ps. if you're an undergraduate, do you prefer talks that solve a problem (or outline a solution), as supposed to talks that introduce a subject from the beginning?

Comment: Your "PS" comment is an entirely different question - maybe you want to ask it?

Comment: @Amy: I certainly agree with Hans, this should be posted a Community Wiki sort of question. As for the answer on that question (though I'm a grad student now, I finished my B.Sc. in math only last year) I remember that I liked the mixture of the two, i.e. presenting me the basics of a subject through an outline of a problem (not necessarily the solution though.)

Comment: @Asaf: only moderators can make questions Community Wiki on SE2 websites. So please do not fault Amy or other users for that.

Comment: @Willie: Read closely what I wrote. This question is not CW at all. She asked a second question in the comments, and this one should be opened on its own, and as CW.

Comment: @Asaf: I hate to repeat myself. But *regular users do not have the abilities to make a question community wiki*. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/941/community-wiki-checkbox-disappeared If you think a question should be made community wiki, you need to flag for moderator attention. Telling that a user should be "posted as a Community Wiki" is telling him or her to do the impossible.

Comment: @Willie: I hate to repeat myself. I only said that the question in the comments should be opened in a separate post. Then it should be made CW. I didn't tell her to do it by herself.

Answer (score 1):

While I personally don't remember the mathematics, I can give you two leads which, if you follow it up, should give you some ideas.

- Try contacting [Jordan Ellenberg](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~ellenber/). Several years ago he gave a talk to the Princeton University Undergraduate Math Club on precisely what you described in your question. He will definitely be able to give you some pointers.
- Also, try asking [Aaron Potechin](http://www-math.mit.edu/people/profile.php?pid=1272). he is an expert Set player and I remember seeing a pre-print of his on the Maximal Cap issue a few years ago, when he was still an undergrad.

Comment: BTW, Jordan's talk introduced, if I remember correctly, vector spaces over finite fields, and from there led to a nice discussion of arithmetic geometry. The ideas are very accessible, but has enough non-intuitive "Whoa" moments that made the talk very engaging.